# How can I sniff unix dgram socket without having file path?

Tags: linux, socat, unix-sockets, ss

From [that article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.14/gtpc1/unixsock.html), I realized that:

> a UNIX domain socket is bound to a file path.

So, I need to sniff DGRAM Unix socket through the `socat` as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/484671/can-i-monitor-a-local-unix-domain-socket-like-tcpdump). But when I try to retrieve the path for this purpose, I find that the target application uses a socket without file path.

The `ss -apex` command shows results both with and without file paths, e.g.:

```
u_dgr UNCONN 0 0 /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/32222   1345285 * 0   users:(("nmbd",pid=32222,fd=7))
u_dgr UNCONN 0 0 * 8567674   * 0   users:(("gnome-shell",pid=16368,fd=23))
```

From the [ss man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) I can't find out, what does it mean e.g. `* 8567674` without file path.

So, two questions:

1. Why there is no file path to unix socket for some cases?
2. How can I sniff unix DGRAM socket through `socat` without having file path?

Comment: These are sockets that have no address set because for example `bind()` wasn't called on them or they were created with `socketpair()`. See definition of `unix_seq_show()` in linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Question #1

> Q1: From the ss man page I can't find out, what does it mean e.g. * 8567674 without file path.

From [the docs it explains](https://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html) the Address:Port column like so:

*excerpt*

> The format and semantics of *ADDRESS_PATTERN* depends on address family.
>
> - ***inet*** - *ADDRESS_PATTERN* consists of IP prefix, optionally followed by colon and port. If prefix or port part is absent or replaced with *, this means wildcard match.
> - ***inet6*** - The same as *inet*, only prefix refers to an IPv6 address. Unlike *inet* colon becomes ambiguous, so that ss allows to use scheme, like used in URLs, where address is suppounded with [ ... ].
> - ***unix*** - *ADDRESS_PATTERN* is shell-style wildcard.
> - ***packet*** - format looks like *inet*, only interface index stays instead of port and link layer protocol id instead of address.
> - ***netlink*** - format looks like *inet*, only socket pid stays instead of port and netlink channel instead of address.
>
> *PORT* is syntactically *ADDRESS_PATTERN* with wildcard address part. Certainly, it is undefined for UNIX sockets.

The last sentence is your answer.

#### Question #2

> Q2: Why there is no file path to unix socket for some cases?

See this SO Q&A titled: [How to use unix domain socket without creating a socket file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427769/how-to-use-unix-domain-socket-without-creating-a-socket-file).

*excerpt*

> You can create a unix domain socket with an "abstract socket address". Simply make the first character of the `sun_path` string in the `sockaddr_un` you pass to bind be `'\0'`. After this initial `NUL`, write a string to the remainder of `sun_path` and pad it out to `UNIX_PATH_MAX` with `NULs` (or anything else).
>
> Sockets created this way will not have any filesystem entry, ....

#### Question #3

> Q3: How can I sniff unix DGRAM socket through socat without having file path?

Again more googling once you know what things are called: [socat docs](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html).

*excerpt*

> - **ABSTRACT-LISTEN:**
> - **ABSTRACT-SENDTO:**
> - **ABSTRACT-RECVFROM:**
> - **ABSTRACT-RECV:**
> - **ABSTRACT-CLIENT:**
>     >
>
>   > The ABSTRACT addresses are almost identical to the related UNIX addresses except that they do not address file system based sockets
>   >     but an alternate UNIX domain address space. To archive this the socket
>   >     address strings are prefixed with "\0" internally. This feature is
>   >     available (only?) on Linux. Option groups are the same as with the
>   >     related UNIX addresses, except that the ABSTRACT addresses are not
>   >     member of the NAMED group.